# Azure pipeline fails to build Docker container - fails to fetch Ubuntu packages

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a pipeline to build a Docker container from a DevOps repo and push to an Azure container registry. The build and Dockerfile build perfectly fine on my local machine but it seems like the build service in Azure fails to connect to the download mirrors for Ubuntu packages. I get the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-137.154_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Fetched 8,100 kB in 7min 33s (17.9 kB/s)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get upgrade -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get upgrade -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# example Dockerfile to expose a plumber service

FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.2
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Install required libraries
RUN apt-get install -y \
  libssl-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libsodium-dev \
  unixodbc-dev \
  r-cran-rodbc \
  libxml2-dev
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools17/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools17/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# install the required packages package
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("dplyr", "devtools", "caret", "plumber", "readr", "yaml", "swagger", "RODBC"), dependencies = T)'
RUN R -e 'library(devtools)'
RUN R -e 'devtools::install_version(package = "xgboost", version = "1.6.0.1", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")'


# Copy everything in current folder to Docker container
COPY / /
# Expose the port
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1433
# Run 
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "model_expose.R"]
```

EDIT:
I followed the GUI inside DevOps to create a pipeline that builds and deploys and image to an Azure container registry. I'm a little new to this so I'm not sure what build agent is being used but I can say that it's not a self hosted one.

The pipeline is a `yml` pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: <cnxn>
  imageRepository: <Image repo name>
  containerRegistry: <Azure container reg>
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tracking/4_docker_container/dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Comment: Could you please add the following info to your question: 1. Which type of build agent are you using? 2. Which type of pipeline are you using? Is it `yml` based or GUI based. If it is `yml`, share the snippet. If GUI based, share the task details and inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've added the details above.
I'm new to this so I'm not 100% what the build agent is. I'm not using a self hosted one. I just followed the GUI prompts in devops prompts in devops to generate the yml and set up the pipeline